# Бинарный поиск, требование к массиву

Tags: алгоритм, двоичный-поиск

Думал всегда, что это какой то сложный алгоритм, но посмотрев понял, что фигня. Но сказали, что реализовать я его не смогу. Решил попробовать и за пару ночных часиков получил удачный алгоритм.

*Подсказок пока не хочу*, есть лишь один вопрос, ответ на который я в явном виде не нахожу (опять же не хочу случайно прочитать подсказки).

Скажите какие условия к массиву, чтобы можно было выполнять бинарный поиск. Упорядоченность это раз. А возрастающий или убывающий  он мы должны знать?

Знаю, что можно проверить какой он и в зависимости от этого выбирать тот или иной алгоритм. Но если окажется, что алгоритм должен быть универсален и для убывающего и для возрастающего, то моя реализация похоже не канает. 

 Остается только добавить условие и если массив убывающий использовать обратный алгоритм.

```
 Integer binarySearch(int value) { 
        middle = array.length / 2;
        lastElement = array.length;
        firstElement = 0;

        while (array[middle] != value) {
            if (array[middle] < value) {
                firstElement = middle;
                middle = (middle + lastElement) / 2;
                if (middle == firstElement) return null;
            } else {
                lastElement = middle;
                middle = (firstElement + lastElement) / 2;
                if (middle == lastElement) return null;
            }
        }
        return middle;
    }
```

**UPD**  Нашел две ошибки в своей реализации бинарного поиска. Искал ошибку, которая была в JDK 20 лет, но сперва нашел, что массив без элементов свалит мой код. Поэтому надо добавить, вот такую проверку :  `if(array.length == 0) return null;` 
 
Чуть позже нашел вторую ошибку, которая была в JDK, не находил её потому, что не рассматривал ситуацию, что может прийти число не int диапазона. Да, не int диапазон не придет, но он может появиться далее в строке  `middle = (firstElement + lastElement) / 2;`  Поэтому переписал её так `middle = firstElement/2 + lastElement/2` Но потом решил, что операция деления более затратная, чем вычитания или сложения и написал вот так

```
middle = (lastElement - firstElement)/2 + firstElement;
```

Comment: вообще лучше знать.

Comment: Проверить два числа (два рядом могут оказаться одинаковыми!), по ним определить возрастание/убывание. По результату применить алгоритм. Логика одинакова, только менять направление.

Comment: да, логика одинакова, но кода в два раза больше ) отдельный кусок кода на обратное направление. И еще один алгоритм для определения возр. или убыв.

Comment: Да, строки добавляются (проверка флага направления), но не в два раза больше А чтобы быстро, без проверок - два почти одинаковых кода

Comment: ну ясно, я просто думал, вдруг я что нибудь не учел и есть универсальный алгоритм, которому не важно возр. массив или убывающий. Если немного подумать, то становится очевидным, что такое невозможно.

Comment: Немного подумайте и придумайте - в чем вопрос? )

Comment: https://habr.com/post/91605/

Comment: ну ответ я получил) : нет такого алгоритма, который будет работать и при убыв. и  возр. Значит я всё уже сделал верно, осталось просто условие добавить , чтобы искать в обратной стороне. Уже сделанный мною код сейчас вывожу в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Требования весьма простые:

1. Должен существовать алгоритм поиска среднего элемента, находящегося между двумя заданными элементами, за константное время
2. Массив должен предоставлять доступ к элементу с заданным индексом за константное время
3. Для всех элементов в рассматриваемом диапазоне массива должна быть определена функция порядка `F(x)`, причем

   - F(x<sub>i</sub>) ≤ F(x<sub>j</sub>) для любых i < j
   - Если F(x<sub>i</sub>) = F(x<sub>j</sub>), то это равносильно утверждению x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>j</sub>

Comment: Какие то странные требования ... и каким же образом методом разделяй и властвуй можно получить константное время и при массиве из 100 элементов и в массиве из 10 000 000 элементов? Да никак

Comment: ааа...не так прочитал. Должен по индексу выдавать элемент, а не по элементу индекс. Ну это "обычный"  массив.

Comment: @TuralllbТо, что вы называете "обычным массивом" может быть реализацией связанного списка. Например, объект класса `LinkedList` в Java предоставляет доступ к элементу с произвольным индексом, но делает это за **линейное** время

Comment: нет, связный список  я не называю обычным массивом ) обычный массив это обычный )) , где в одном выделенном участке памяти последовательно лежат элементы )